# Can't submit form after jquery.html() into jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm loading form into jquery-ui dialog using jquery.html() function and then Submitting doesn't work (alert doesnt show) - can someone tell me why?

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/GMcev/11/

Comment: because it is `type="submit"`, on clicking , it is submitting form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delegate event. Because your button is added to DOM after page load ie. dynamically, so you need something like following:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function() {
    alert('TEST!'); //it doesnt work            
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GMcev/13/)**

Comment: But you see, I'm loading some form into my ui dialog after click the link (after the dom is ready i think) and I want to submit it via ajax - will it work using one of yours methods?

Answer (score 2):

Call

```
$(".button").click(function() {  
            alert('aaa');
```

in open action of dialog

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "contact",
        open: function() {
            $(".button").click(function() {
                alert('aaa');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

i suggest to put onclick in submit button

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' class='button' 
id='submit' value='Zapisz' onclick='dingDong()' />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GexFz/1/